# adding a local/custom domain on a windows LAN network (without editing host files)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, local-area-network

I did find somewhat similar questions here, this one shows first I think, on google:
[Modify DNS cache other than HOSTS file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7270/modify-dns-cache-other-than-hosts-file)

This one too:
[Windows DNS Manager and Sub Domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/41744/windows-dns-manager-and-sub-domains)

I also found this article:
http://www.petri.co.il/install_and_configure_windows_2003_dns_server.htm

But I'm still not clear, I'm a programmer here, so here is what I need to do:

**Question**:
I work with a client who has a **large** LAN network, they use host files to add a domain name (which takes a lot of time).

The network has static IP addresses assigned to each PC.

How do I add a domain to this network, assuming I have access to whatever servers they use?

I'd just like some basic info going from the links above, would I use DNS manager? What range do I add?  The static, assigned IPs are arranged like 10.region.floor.xxx (and there are a mighty lot of them)

The admins actually guide each guys network guys in each region to edit the host file, the problem is I have an app running there, and it points to a server with an IP address like (http://10.1.10.1/service.svc) and when the servers change I have trouble, so I want to add a domain and have my app point to it.

Working with Windows here, my server will prolly be Windows 2003 R2 or 2008.

**Update** Just to be clearer, I want www.myexample.com to point to a server of my choice on the LAN. My app should only query the domain (just like on the web) and should not have trouble if the server changes (and I should be able to change the server later)

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "domain" you mean that you want to create a forward lookup zone in DNS and have host records in that zone that point to your servers? If so, and they don't currently have a DNS server running, you can add the DNS server role to an existing server then open up the DNS manager MMC snap in and create a forward DNS zone for whatever domain you want to create. Add host records for your servers in the zone and assign them the correct IP addresses. You can choose to create the reverse zones and PTR records if you want, they aren't necessary though.

You have to be sure that your clients are pointing to the DNS server you just setup in their TCP/IP settings. If this is an Active Directory domain with integrated DNS zones, you can point the DNS manager at any domain controller and create the zone there. Your clients can point to any domain controller to resolve the DNS records you created as long as the zone you created is AD integrated.

Comment: +1 thanks, I'm a little fuzzy though, (also updated the Q) Each pc has a static IP and they each have DNS servers already configured. So I will have to play with **that** server to add a lookup right? Hmm not sure about AD will have to ask the guys there.

Comment: yes. If the clients already point to a DNS server, just create the forward zone there and add your hosts. As long as those hosts don't already exist in the hosts file on the client PC's, it will resolve them correctly. The whole static IP address for your clients doesn't matter and you can drop that from the equation.